# Add JLayer Library Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mp3

I have a problem with JLayer Library on Eclipse. With JDev it works fine but I have to work in Eclipse for a project and I can't install this Library.
I did Builds Path -> Add Library and import JLayer.zip
As you can see I can't import Javazoom. Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: 'import' statements go **before** the class definition

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the JLayer zip file to extract the jar file contains the Java class files (jl1.0.1.jar). Use this jar file in the build path as an external jar instead of the zip file.

Also 'import' statements come before the class file definition:

```
import javazoom.jl.player.AudioDevice;

public class MyClass
{
  ....
}
```